# Generic XOR Swap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swap, xor

Today I was reading about XOR Swaps, and figured I would try to implement a function in Swift that would do this. I successfully wrote a non-generic version of this function:

```
import UIKit

func xorSwap (inout x: Int, inout y: Int) {
    if x != y {
        x ^= y
        y ^= x
        x ^= y
    }
}


var a = 10
var b = 20

xorSwap(&a, &b)

println(a) //=> 20
println(b) //=> 10
```

I then tried writing a generic version of this, but the compiler complained that 'T is not identical to Bool'. I'm assuming there's another protocol I need to declare conformance to, but I'm not sure what that is. Here's the attempt at a generic version:

```
import UIKit

func xorSwap<T: Equatable> (inout x: T, inout y: T) {
    if x != y {
        x ^= y
        y ^= x
        x ^= y
    }
}


var a = 10
var b = 20

xorSwap(&a, &b)

println(a)
println(b)
```

Does anyone have a better understanding of this and can help me fill the gaps in my understanding? Thanks.

Comment: Seriously - don't bother, unless it's just for idle curiosity - XOR swap is just a gimmick and is not particularly useful or efficient.

Comment: Oh yes I should have clarified that this is just a curiosity. I don't see myself using this anywhere but my curiosity is getting the better of me.

Comment: Phew, that's a relief. ;-)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26717104/1187415. The same solution can be applied here.

Comment: I know you're just doing this for curiosity, but note that Swift has a [`swap` function built in](http://swifter.natecook.com/func/swap/).

Comment: What would happen if the the arguments were `floats`? Would that even make sense? Any `Equatable`?

Comment: @NateCook Thanks. I'd definitely use theirs in a real world situation

Comment: For just playing around  since there a `swap` function consider tuples: `(x, y) = (y, x)`.

Comment: @Zaph good point. My knowledge of XORSwap is limited to what I've just read today. So the assumption is that only integer types can be swapped using this method? Or can any type be swapped in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use built-in `BitwiseOperationsType`

```
func xorSwap<T: protocol<BitwiseOperationsType, Equatable>> (inout x: T, inout y: T) {
    if x != y {
        x ^= y
        y ^= x
        x ^= y
    }
}

var a = 10
var b = 20

xorSwap(&a, &b)

println(a) // -> 20
println(b) // -> 10
```

---

```
var a = NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch
var b = NSStringCompareOptions.BackwardsSearch

xorSwap(&a, &b)

a == .BackwardsSearch // -> true
b == .CaseInsensitiveSearch // -> true
```

Comment: Another syntax would be func xorSwap<T where T: Equatable, T: BitwiseOperationsType> (inout x: T, inout y: T)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks! One question though on syntax: Does protocol<BitwiseOperationsType, Equatable> declare that the type must conform to both BitwiseOperationsType and Equatable? I was under the assumption that you could just declare the protocols separated by a comma, but the compiler doesn't like that.

Comment: It's called "Protocol Composition", see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_424

Answer (score 0):

Your function performs two kinds of operations on its arguments: `!=` and xor.

The type constraints you specified only guarantee that `T` must be `Equatable` which implicitly gives you `!=`.

You have to add a constraint that guarantees xor:

```
// protocol that guarantees ^ operator
protocol Xorable {
    func ^(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

// declare Int to support xor
extension Int : Xorable {}

// Your slightly modified function that depends on xor and Equatable
func xorSwap<T : protocol<Xorable, Equatable>> (inout x: T, inout y: T) {
    if x != y {
        x = x ^ y
        y = y ^ x
        x = x ^ y
    }
}
```